# OpenCL including cl.h in code::blocks on Windows

Tags: c, include, opencl

Configuration question here, will hopefully help others in the future.

I created a folder, "C:\openCLcode\include\" which has all the necessary files from the Khronos site: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/

Now I want to create a Code::Blocks project that runs openCL. So I paste in some sample code and change the include paths:

In my .c file:

```
#include <C:\openCLcode\include\cl.h>
```

And within that `cl.h` file it complained about `cl_platform.h` so I fixed that path too:

```
#include <C:\openCLcode\include\cl_platform.h>
```

Now the problem I get is: `undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs@12'` Here is the offending function and line:

```
cl_device_id create_device() {

   cl_platform_id platform;
   cl_device_id dev;
   int err;

   /* Identify a platform */
    //////////////THIS IS THE LINE WITH ERROR:////////////
   err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Access a device */
   err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
   if(err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
      err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
   }
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't access any devices");
      exit(1);
   }

   return dev;
}
```

I feel like I really screwed up my include scheme.... Could someone recommend a better way to go about this?

Much appreciated

Comment: Undefined reference usually means you are not linking all the libraries.

Comment: What is this and how can I do this? Within Code::Blocks I am using the GNU GCC compiler. I thought all I had to do was include header files and I'm good. Clearly not..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link libOpenCL.a library to your project.

1) Right click on you project(in codeblocks)

2) Select "Build options"

3) Select tab "Linker settings"

4) Press "Add" button

5) Select path with openCL libraries and choose libOpenCL.a.

Or you can compile OpenCL with you project:) Just add all openCL .cpp files in you project and try build it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do not seem to have libOpenCL.a, I will try downloading and linking with that.

Comment: IT WORKED! I generated libOpenCL.a from OpenCL.dll using "gendef" in my MinGW shell. And as a result I ran my first openCL program.